# Regex - Parsing Parts of a URL in JMeter

Tags: parsing, url, jmeter

I am trying to parse parts of the URL that I received from an API. I am trying to do this using Regex in Jmeter and save it into Variables.

I have a URL which looks like

I receive a URL as part of an API response and have extracted the URL into a variable named "UploadUrl". The value is similar to

https://Domain/path1/path2?queryParam1=Value1&queryParam2=Value2

I need to extract
Protocol as https
Host as Domain
Path as path1/path2
Parameters as queryParam1=Value1&queryParam2=Value2

so that I can pass them as inputs in the JMeter http Sampler.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjzCe.png)

but when I run the JMeter script the value is not getting extracted via the Regex.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put everything into "Path" field of the HTTP Request sampler

   [image]
2. If you still want to extract protocol, host and so on it would be way easier to do using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and some [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like:

   ```
   URL url = new URL(vars.get('UploadUrl'))

   def protocol = url.getProtocol()
   def host = url.getHost()
   def port = url.getPort()
   if (port == -1) {
       port = url.getDefaultPort()
   }
   def path = url.getPath()
   def query = url.getQuery()

   vars.put('protocol', protocol)
   vars.put('host', host)
   vars.put('port', port as String)
   vars.put('path', path)
   vars.put('query', query)
   ```

Demo:

[image]

You will be able to access the values like `${host}`, `${port}`, etc. where required.

Comment: Thank you for your help on the same. The Groovy Script worked great